# C# Drawing a graph using QuickGraph and GraphViz

Tags: c#, graphviz, quickgraph

I hope I don't appear lazy, but I am really struggling to draw a graph using QuickGraph and GraphViz, since I can't appear to find much documentation online. I am quite new to C# interfaces, so am finding them quite confusing as well. Would anybody be able to give me a simple working example, or direct me so some good examples and documentation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Quickgraph-to-Graphviz-export can not write files, so you need to implement IDotEngine which handles the file writing.

```
public class FileDotEngine : IDotEngine
{    
    public string Run(GraphvizImageType imageType, string dot, string outputFileName)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFileName))
        {
            writer.Write(dot);    
        }

        return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(outputFileName);
    }
}
```

Then you can call the Graphviz Algorithm like this:

```
GraphvizAlgorithm<TNode, TEdge> graphviz = new GraphvizAlgorithm<TNode, TEdge>(this.Graph);
graphviz.FormatVertex += (sender, args) => args.VertexFormatter.Comment = args.Vertex.Label;
graphviz.FormatEdge += (sender, args) => { args.EdgeFormatter.Label.Value = args.Edge.Label; };

graphviz.Generate(new FileDotEngine(), filePath);
```

The created dotfile can be passed to graphviz. [See Graphviz Dot usage here in the dotguide](http://graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf)

Comment: Thank you clx. The program now generates a graph but the vertices aren't labelled correctly. I suppose this is to do with the 'FormatVertex' and 'FormatEdge' event handling lines. My IDE doesn't like the 'Label' in `args.Vertex.Label` or `args.Edge.Label`, however. Any idea why not?

Comment: @LordCat There is no `Label` property in `TNode` and `TEdge`. Following from [this example on GitHub](https://github.com/serra/QuickgraphExamples/blob/master/src/examples/Support/Visualizer.cs#L55), maybe you should just do nothing for `.FormatEdge` event; and for `.FormatVertex`, just do `args.VertexFormatter.Label = args.Vertex.ToString();`